# How do i backup mysql in Grails3

Tags: mysql, grails, groovy

I don't know does grails3 have the default api to dump my database. 
But when I execute the shell command `mysqldump -u root -ppass *** >> /***.sql` in groovy and the cmd is not work with some message from `execute().text`

`-- MySQL dump 10.13 Distrib 5.7.14, for osx10.11 (x86_64) -- -- Host: localhost Database: grailstest -- ------------------------------------------------------ -- Server version    5.7.14 /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */; /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */; /*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */; /*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */; /*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */; /*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */; /*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */; /*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */; /*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */; /*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;`

Answer (score 0):

OK，I solved the problem, just execute the 'musqldump' command without '> *.sql', then redirect the Process.inputStream to another .sql file